# Wordpress, hide posts from main page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have some automatic generated posts in my system, `wp_posts` table has additional field `auto`, by default this field is NULL, but for my specific posts it have some value. I don't wont to show such posts on main page, how can I hide them?

I think I need something like:

```
function exclude_post($query) {
    if ($query->is_home) {
        ...
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_post');
```

how can I add conditions like SQL `"auto IS NOT NULL"`?

Comment: You would be much better off adding your "auto" as post meta rather than manually adding extra columns to core wordpress tables

Comment: As Anigel said the better way to do it is to add a post meta and exclude them in your main page WP_Query.

Comment: If you were to use post meta you could then simply use the [get_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) function to see if it was an "auto" post or not

Comment: Ok, how can I do that with meta, I need some additional record for such posts in `wp_postmeta` table?

Comment: Just use [add_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta) to create a meta record for that post with a meta_key of "auto" or whatever you want to call it and the appropriate meta_value

Comment: STOP! I have that field in any case, I asked how don't show posts on home page, but not how to migrate field from posts table to meta. Somebody have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you were following other users suggestions and changed to post meta instead of an additional column in the posts table you could add:

```
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    array(
        'key' => 'meta_key_for_auto',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
) );
```

If you're going to stick with the column in the posts table then pre_get_posts probably isn't the best hook to use. Instead look at posts_where.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where